# How to add gradient effect to background color of TextView in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, textview, gradient, background-color

In reference to these questions:

[Adding gradient effect to TextView in a ListView generates NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361772/adding-gradient-effect-to-textview-in-a-listview-generates-npe)
[How to change color and font on ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361135/how-to-change-color-and-font-on-listview)

I would like to know how to go about setting the background of a `TextView` in a `ListView` with gradient effect?

In one of the questions above, I ended up having the gradient effect added to the text in the `TextView`. And after skimming through the second question, it seems I can add only fixed background colors.

How do I go about adding gradient to the background?

Should I make a `CustomListAdapter`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1683195/1339473 this is link may be help you

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You just need to create a drawable resource (see an example below), and add it to the layout you created for your ListItem.

The drawable (in your res\drawable folder - name it whatever - listgrad.xml for ex) could look like:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
      android:startColor="@color/gradient_start"
      android:endColor="@color/gradient_end"
      android:angle="-270" /> 
</shape>
```

The you would add it to the layout for your list item (the layout.xml file you define for this) like this code snippet:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/ranking_order"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_grad"
        />
...
```

Comment: thanks but i want only gradient for textview not backgroud. how can i do?

Comment: You can't apply gradient to a TextView FWIW, @SaiGopiMe (I see your question is 3 years old, but better late then never).

Comment: @saigopi.me, you can use this Library to apply gradient on a textview
https://github.com/veeyaarVR/SuperGradientTextView

It worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Yuck, why would you add a 3rd party lib, to handle such a simple thing?  I don't want another dependency in my app.

Answer (score 11):

Once you create a gradient you can apply it to pretty much anything let it be textView, layout or button.

To understand how to create and use a gradient refer [**this link**](http://www.singhajit.com/gradient-color-in-android/).

To create a gradient you need to add it to the below directory

[image]

Code for gradient would be something like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff2d9a59"
                android:centerColor="#ff42959a"
                android:endColor="#ff23729a"
                android:angle="135"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3):

Referred from here : [How do I create a ListView with rounded corners in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683185/how-do-i-create-a-listview-with-rounded-corners-in-android/1683195#1683195)
(I have found it very useful.)

Add the following into a file (say gradient.xml) and then place it in (res/drawable/gradient.xml) directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle"> 
     <gradient 
         android:startColor="#SomeGradientBeginColor"
         android:endColor="#SomeGradientEndColor" 
         android:angle="270"/> 

    <corners 
         android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" 
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Once you are done with creating this file,just set the background in one of the following ways:

Through Code: `listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.customshape);`

Through XML,just add the following attribute to the container (ex: LinearLayout or to any fields):

```
android:background="@drawable/customshape"
```