# Element must be declared error for tag shape

Tags: android, gradle

**I'm using Android Studio I/O(Preview) 0.3.2**

I'm using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364617/how-can-i-add-gradient-effect-to-background-color-of-textview-in-a-listview) to define background gradient in my app. I get Element must be declared error. [image]

I've checked and I'm not find any solutions. Can anyone help me how can I declare that tag in the xml

Comment: For any future readers, a sort of annoying pitfall of Studio is that if you right click on the drawable folder to create new xml, it automatically places that xml file in "values" or "layout" depending on your choice. I've found it best to just go with "new file"

Comment: in my case, i delete that file folder and then add it back.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

This problem was caused by my xml file. My gradient XML file was in the `values` folder, I solved this problem by moving gradient file to `drawable` folder

Comment: This issue appeared to me when I tried to use a TextView for an ArrayAdapter. My issue got fixed by moving the xml file from drawable to layout.

Comment: It looks like we android, it's important to know your project structure and where to place certain xml files

Comment: Yes, I was having a ScrollView element problem in my xml file. I copied the created file to may layout folder and the error has gone now.

Comment: Where should I put the resource file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources> <item type="id" name="action_bar_activity_content" /> </resources>? It's in values and I am getting the error

Comment: Or you can create a new folder like raw and put your xml file's (or other data file's) on it.

Answer (score 21):

You could just right click

> res

and hit

> New

, to create a

> Android Resource File

, and choose

> Resource Type

to be

> Drawable

, and change whatever the default

> root element

to

> shape

Yeah it's kinda buggy in Android Studio to create a new XML file other than layout and values lol.

hope it can help you!!

Comment: Where should I put the resource file `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    <item type="id" name="action_bar_activity_content" /> </resources>`? It's in values and I am getting the error.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem with Android Studio , I created a directory "anim" under "res" then copied the xml file to that one then the error gone.

Comment: Where should I put the resource file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources> <item type="id" name="action_bar_activity_content" /> </resources>? It's in values and I am getting the error

Answer (score 11):

You need to use selector inside `<set/>` tags like that;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="15dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </item>
        <item>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="5dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </item>
    </selector>
</set>
```

Answer (score 7):

Had a similar problem with the selector tag used to create a state list animator.

My animation was in the anim resource folder. Had to move it to the animator folder.

Comment: I also tried to make <animation-list> in "anim" and "animator", but this hadn't helped.

Comment: Because <animation-list> must be placed in a "drawable" folder as written in https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/frame-animations-in-android/.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem. I had created a StateListAnimator to change the elevation on button press and it only worked in either `drawable` or `animator` folders, even though some online resources claimed to put it into `anim`, which didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at that example, I think if you add the `xmlns:android` attribute (inside the shape tag, as in the example that you are following), it will work:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

I suspect that `shape` is declared there.

Comment: That doesn't work. I copied everything and I still get that error

Comment: @Simon That is strange - it works fine for me. Have you tried refreshing your project?

Comment: Tried to compile, closed and opened android studio. Still nothing works. Maybe there is a problem with Android Studio

Comment: @Simon - sorry - if that doesn't work then I have no clue... You could check if this is a problem in Android Studio by downloading the community version of intellij and trying your code there, but beyond that I have no suggestions